# How to display a personalized message when I use a query-importrange in Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, importrange

I'm using a query function with importrange but I need a personalized message when query couldn't find anything in the database. Currently I'm using this formula.

```
=QUERY(
  {
    IMPORTRANGE("url", "'Parte 1'!A1:AH");
    IMPORTRANGE("url", "'Parte 2'!A1:AH");
    IMPORTRANGE("url", "'Parte 3'!A1:AH");
    IMPORTRANGE("url", "'Parte 4'!A1:AH")
  }, "Select Col2, Col1, Col34, Col24, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col11, Col7, Col8, 
             Col9, Col10, Col12, Col13, Col14, Col15, Col20, Col21, Col22, Col23 
      Where Col10="&$C$1&" And Col22 != 'Duplicado'")
```

Comment: How do you want this personalized message to be displayed? Like an error message, with the red flag? A value in the cell? A popup window?

Comment: I meant a message like "There's no data related  with ID queried" on the cells returned when query didn't find anything in the master database. It's almost the same function like "iferror" but in this case is when there's no data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({
 IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE("url", "'Parte 1'!A1:AH"), 
         {"1 not working", SUBSTITUTE(COLUMN(B:AH)^0, 1, )});
 IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE("url", "'Parte 2'!A1:AH"), 
         {"2 not working", SUBSTITUTE(COLUMN(B:AH)^0, 1, )});
 IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE("url", "'Parte 3'!A1:AH"), 
         {"3 not working", SUBSTITUTE(COLUMN(B:AH)^0, 1, )});
 IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE("url", "'Parte 4'!A1:AH"),
         {"4 not working", SUBSTITUTE(COLUMN(B:AH)^0, 1, )})}, 
 "select Col2,Col1,Col34,Col24,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col11,Col7,Col8,
         Col9,Col10,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col15,Col20,Col21,Col22,Col23 
  where Col10="&$C$1&" 
    and Col22 != 'Duplicado'
     or Col1 contains 'not working'"))
```